# SBS 2003 Setting up server with internal website

Tags: iis-6, windows-sbs-2003, microsoft-dynamics-gp

I have a server running Microsoft SBS 2003 (no exchange).  I have IIS installed, and need to get the server address to open a different address opposed to the standard companyweb.

Right now when you navigate to my server on the domain http://crm -- it comes up with the "Welcome to Windows Small Business Server 2003 To get started, click a link." page.  But I need it to load a site from Programfiles > CRM > CRM web instead.  And also have it accessible on port :5555.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new web site bound to "All Unassigned" IP addresses for ports 80 and 5555 and select the "CRM" directory you referenced as the web site's home directory. Configure a "Host Header" on the port 80 binding for "crm" (and create a host header for "crm.fully-qualified-domain.com" if you want it to be accessible with the FQDN, too). Finally, create a CNAME record in your domain's DNS zone for "crm" referring to the name of the Windows SBS Server computer.

That will preserve the default web site configuration (which you may need for other services-- Remote Web Workplace being the main one I can think of) but give you what you're looking for.

Edit:

I've got a couple of minutes while I'm waiting on some files to copy so I thought I'd feed my Server Fault addiction... >smile<

This is Microsoft's Dynamics CRM software, eh?  (I got that from reading your other questions... I hadn't looked there until this moment). I don't have any experience with this software. I suspect that there's more configuration in the web site that the product's installer creates than just pointing it at a "home directory" and leaving the rest of the IIS settings as-default. A fairly determine searching effort isn't bringing me to any documents that describe what to do if you've deleted this web site by accident (which would be a similar scenario), so I can't say for sure what needs to be done to create the site.

I suspect that IIS 6 may not be setting the proper default document name and there may be some authentication issues, too (like not allowing anonymous access to the default document to force authentication). That's just my gut talking after reading the few things I did.

If this server isn't production for any other role I'd beat on the setup a little more, concentrating in particular on any logs the setup might generate that could give you some clues as to why it's not creating its web site.

Comment: OK, I have my site in there, I have all others "stopped" (I don't need any others) - its "all unassigned" with port 5555, but I don't know how to have it have two ports as you suggested? I can't do 80,5555 in the properties window...

Comment: @bMon: You can add multiple bindings for the site. You need to go to the "Advanced..." dialog (from the "Web Site" tab of the site's Properties sheet) and add the additional bindings under "Multiple identities for this web site".

Comment: I'm having problems adding the CNAME "A alias (cname) cannot be added to this dns name.  The dns name contains records that are incompatible with the CNAME."  Is this step necessary?  I have one site under the IIS shouldn't I be able to access it via http://crm or the IP of the server?  My parent issue with all this is my CRM install is completing and the last step is to point to the CRM server (which is the same server) but it doesn't see it.  The install put all the files in the IIS automatically - it just serving up those files for the http://crm like it should.

Comment: @bMon: You're not going to be able to access the "CRM" site via the machine's IP address unless you add a host header for the IP address to the site. re: the CNAME - What *exactly* are you trying to add for a CNAME? I'm expecting that you're adding a CNAME to the DNS zone for your domain with the "Alias name" set to "crm" (w/o quotes) and the "Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for target host" set to "SBS-server-name.yourdomain.com". Is that what you're adding?

Comment: I'm going to DNS>CRM>Forward Look up Zones > company.local - then in there are 5 entries: SOA, NS, A, CNAME (which is named companyweb with crm.company.local. as the data) and last is Host(A) with the name crm and the server IP as the data.

Comment: I just was able to add it to the DNS>CRM>Forward Look up Zones > company.local > DomainDnsZones.. is that the right spot?

Comment: @bMon: Woah there! It sounds like you're saying that the Windows SBS computer's name is "crm". If that's the case then you don't need to add a CNAME record because the computer's name is "crm" to begin with. I assumed the server computer's name wasn't "crm". The "DomainDnsZones" isn't where you wanted to add this record. It shouldn't hurt anything there but for cleanliness you should remove it. So-- after creating the site and specifying the appropriate host header for the port 80 binding you should find that you can access the CRM site from "http://crm" on a client computer.

Comment: I hope you're still around!  OK I cleaned it up.  And yes, the SBS computer name is crm - sorry I didn't say. So now I have the one CRM site in the IIS running with port 5555, then under website identification > advanced - I have 3 entries the 5555 with no host header, 80 with host header crm, and 80 with crm.company.local.  Right now I don't have access to other nodes on the domain, but when I navigate to http://crm on the server I get the "page cannot be found" message.  And when I send my install to http://crm:5555 it just hangs, and I have to quit the install..any other ideas?

Comment: Also my Event Viewer is throwing 2errors / 1warning every minute. Error - SQLSERVERAGENT, Error - (Microsoft.Crm.Tools.FaxConnectorService.FaxSinkServiceException: Failed to initialize the fax analysis module for folder: [CRMServerUrl:'http://CRM:5555' Folder:'C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM\Server\bin\fax\incoming'] (Microsoft.Crm.Tools.FaxConnectorService.FaxSinkServiceException: ....) AND Warning - MSCRMFaxRouterService.  Any other problem solving techniques?

Comment: Sorry just noticed your edit - thanks.  Yes it is MS Dynamics CRM 3.0 - and yes, I have been struggling finding documentation, hence the server fault post :) - I appreciate you taking some time. I'm gonna keep plugging away and if you have any other ideas please let me know.